# Problema ao tentar abrir porta em um servidor linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor

Olá, estou tendo um problema ao tentar abrir uma porta no meu VPS linux Ubuntu. Estou querendo criar um servidor ftp, mas não consigo abrir a porta 21. O pessoal do suporte disse que todas as portas já vem abertas por padrão, mas parece que a 21 não está aberta.

Eu já tentei de diversas formas. Esse é um dos comandos que rodei para alterar a configuração do firewall

iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp –-dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp –-dport 21 -j ACCEPT

Já tentei usando o "ufw" e também tentei usando o "csf"

Mas sem sucesso. Verifico no nmap e outras ferramentas online, mas sempre mostram que a porta 21 está fechada.

Answer (score 2):

Após validar se sua porta realmente está em pé, utilize os seguintes comandos para liberar *INPUT* e *OUTPUT*.

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Liberar INPUT porta 21"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Liberar OUTPUT porta 21"
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Apliquei esse comando e a porta ainda continua fechada.

Comment: @SrMax tem como postar a sua conf do vsftpd?

Comment: Certifique-se de que o serviço esteja escutando na porta que deseja `netstat -lnap | grep <serviço>`

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. Eu solucionei o problema, não tinha o servidor rodando.